# circular page indicator

Tags: android

While making circular page indicator for page swiping I am getting below error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >    

      <RelativeLayout  android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@+id/winyear"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#36648B" >   

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Product" android:layout_centerInParent="true"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/produt" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager" android:layout_below="@+id/winyear"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

   <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator" android:layout_below="@+id/pager"
         android:padding="10dip" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

```
public class Details extends FragmentActivity{


    ViewPager pager;
  MyFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;     

 CirclePageIndicator mIndicator;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.detail);    
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();      
    pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(fm,currency);   
      pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);


      mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
      mIndicator.setViewPager(pager);
   }
```

> 11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity ComponentInfo{com.contract/com.contract.Details}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at com.contract.Details.onCreate(Details.java:36)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  ... 11 more
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.contract-1.apk]
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
>       11-29 13:08:52.579: E/AndroidRuntime(470):  ... 20 more
>       11-29 13:13:52.652: I/Process(470): Sending signal. PID: 470 SIG: 9

Comment: ClassNotFoundException: com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator

Comment: By changing com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator in to com.detail.CirclePageIndicator (package name) then error is resolved but circlepage indicators are not appearing

Answer (score 1):

This was quite strange to me when I faced this same problem. The application I was developing was working just fine until I reordered few dependency libraries in application's build.gradle file. After reverting back to original order, the application was running successfully.

** Found out using both of these can generate same problem as well, so use only one that you need.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'*/
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'
```

** For me using only compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0' solved the issue.